# Parameter assignment not working as expected

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am working with binary search tree for class assignment. I'm trying to replace a node with a different node by assigning the new node to the recursive method parameter.

The line `node = minNode(node.right);` is not working as expected. It does modify the parameter `SearchTreeNode<E> node` but this change doesn't propagate to `this.overallRoot`. For example, if the root of the tree is 5, and we remove 5, and the substitute would be 7, `this.overallRoot` remains 5 even though the parameter node has been changed to 7. See screenshots below.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
public void remove(E data) {
    if (this.overallRoot != null) {
        this.removeData(this.overallRoot, data);
    }
}

private void removeData(SearchTreeNode<E> node, E data) {
    if (node.data == data) {
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            node = null;
        } else if (node.left != null && node.right != null) {
            node = minNode(node.right);
        } else if (node.right == null) {
            node = node.left;
        } else if (node.left == null) {
            node = node.right;
        }
    } else if (data.compareTo(node.data) < 0) {
        this.removeData(node.left, data);
    } else if (data.compareTo(node.data) > 0) {
        this.removeData(node.right, data);
    }
}

private SearchTreeNode<E> minNode(SearchTreeNode<E> node) {
    if (node.left == null) {
        return node;
    }
    return minNode(node.left);
}
```

[image: Debugging code]
[image: overallRoot with data 5]
[image: node with data 7]

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Stackoverflow is giving me errors, I'm trying to add screenshot as well of the debugging for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagnosis is exactly right: modifying `node` doesn't do any good because `node` is a local variable. Modifications to parameters don't propagate to the caller.

You *can* modify `node.left` and `node.right`, though. Those changes would be visible. You'd need to restructure your code to take advantage of that. It's not a quick fix.

Alternatively, you could return a value to `removeData`'s caller and have the caller change the appropriate variable. That, too, would take some thinking to figure out what to return from each of `removeData`'s branches. Calling it would look like:

```
node.left = this.removeData(node.left, data);
```